# how to export an image into an Excel file without Excel installed (using ASP.Net/VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I need to export Chart(image) and grid (tabular) row data into excel file. I can not use automation because Office tools are not installed in my server. I've found a bunch of free/proprietary tools like:

1. NPOI
2. MyXLS
3. ExcelWriter (softartisans)
4. JetCell (DevTrio)
5. Aspose.Cells (Aspose)

But I do not know which one is better for my needs. I need to export not only grid row data but also Chart (image), thats why I am thinking about. Wolud you please help me?

Thanks,
Ervin

Answer (score 1):

I purchased Spreadsheet Gear for these purposes and have been extremely happy with them.

Alternatively, the XSLX specification (Excel 2007+) is an open standard, and you can do it in that.